# What is the latest (timeline-wise) CANON reference to Romana?

Tags: doctor-who

In Doctor Who, as far as I can recall, the final appearance of Romana is her departing with K-9 to stay in e-space during the run of the Fourth Doctor. I know that she appears again in novels, and possibly some audioplays...but is there a later reference, with regards to timeline, to her character in appearance or dialog?

[The Woman](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Woman) does not, apparently, count, though that would have been far cooler than what The Word of God indicates she was.

Comment: Do you mean last as in last made, or last in the Doctor's timeline?  Sometimes books or other material might be written out of order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whoniverse#Inclusion_and_continuity):

> Steven Moffat declared at a convention in 2008 that, "It is impossible for a show about a dimension-hopping time traveller to have a canon."'

However, if we look at material licensed by the BBC, which controls *Doctor Who* and owns the rights, the last reference in terms of timeline is, as best I can tell, [*The Forgotten*](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Forgotten).  In it, the Doctor muses that Romana did pretty well for herself -- until the Last Great Time War.

Before that, [this article](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Romana) in the [Doctor Who wiki](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Doctor_Who_Wiki) indicates that she was President of the Time Lords until the Time War, but was not at the end, when Rassilon was President.

If you're referring strictly to the TV series, while she makes her last appearance in [*Warrior's Gate*](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Warriors%27_Gate), she is referenced in [*Logopolis*](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Logopolis_%28TV_story%29) when The Doctor and Adric are looking at her room, which is later jettisoned to escape The Master.  This (*Logopolis*) episode is when the 4th Doctor regenerates and becomes the 5th Doctor.  After regenerations, there are usually not references to previous companions.  (And, without watching every episode from then on, I cannot find any other references to her in the original shows and know there have been no direct references in the new shows, since I've been watching for one.)